# Docker for windows compatibility

Tags: windows, docker

Simple question here:
In the Docker Store I see a dropdown list with different OS. e.g.: https://store.docker.com/images/php

Im learning Docker on Windows. My question is, that list represesents the OS in which the app will be deployed to, or the host in which the image is created?

In other words, me being on Windows 10, can I use a Linux image or it just won't work, so I need a linux environment through VirtualBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker for Windows (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) has options to run both Linux and Windows containers. If you want to run Linux images, just run on Linux containers. Please look more detail at https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers.